# Add rel=“noopener noreferrer” to links with target=“_blank” in javascript

Tags: javascript

some of my blog links are disabled in google chrome. when I click a link with `target=“_blank”` it shows me that popup blocker doesn't let it open.
I found some posts about `rel=“noopener noreferrer”`.
Now I want to add `rel=“noopener noreferrer”` to all of the links with `target=“_blank”`.

Comment: Please show some example code, and how you've tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: So add it... Any issues with adding attribute to DOM element? `myElement.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener noreferrer')`

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not much to show and if you do not know how or how to find such code, it is hard to show any

Comment: @mplungjan And if you don't ever search, you definitely won't find anything. And if people answer your question despite having commented that the OP should post effort and code, then no one's going to put in the effort...

Comment: I give the new-ish member a chance to better his ways

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll("a[target=_blank]")]
    .forEach(lnk => lnk.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer"))
);
```